# Does capybara "within" deal with ajax, why failed within the css with the error " unable to find find css "

Tags: cucumber, capybara, capybara-webkit

I have a step like this:

```
Then(/^I can see the Eligible Bugs list "([^"]*)"$/) do |bugs|
  bugs_list = bugs.split(", ")
  assert page.has_css?(".eligible-bugs", :visible => true)
  within(".eligible-bugs") do
    bugs_list.each do |bug|
    assert page.has_content?(bug)
   end
  end
 end
```

But  the step fail sometimes at the " within(".eligible-bugs") do" with the error 'Unable to find css ".eligible-bugs"'

I feel it is odd.
for the assertion has been passed. it means the css is visible.
why within cannot find css? How it happen.

But  the step fail sometimes at the " within(".eligible-bugs") do" with the error 'Unable to find css ".eligible-bugs"'

I feel it is odd.
for the assertion has been passed. it means the css is visible.
why within cannot find css? How it happen.

BTW, I have set my max wait time to 5.

```
   Capybara.default_max_wait_time = 5
```

Answer (score 0):

The only way that should happen, is if the page is dynamically changing while you're running the test - sometime during your check for all bugs content on the page it is changing and the '.eligible-bugs' element is going way.  The test and the browser run separately, so how/why it is happening depends on what else your page is doing in the browser, it would also depend on what steps have come before this in the test.

Also, note that it's not necessarily disappearing between the `has_css?` and the `within` statement first running.  If it disappears at any point during the code inside the `within` running it could throw the same error as it attempts to reload the '.eligible-bugs' element.

From the title of the question I assume the list that you want to check is the result of a search or filtering action.  If it is, does that action remove the existing '.eligible-bugs' element and then after some time replace it with a new one returned from an ajax request or something?  If that is the case then, since you control the test data, you should be waiting for the correct results count to show, thereby ensuring any element replacements have completed, before checking for the text.  How you do that would depend on the exact makeup of the page, but if each eligible bug was a child of '.eligible-bugs' and had a class of '.eligible-bug' I would write your test something like

```
Then(/^I can see the Eligible Bugs list "([^"]*)"$/) do |bugs|
  bugs_list = bugs.split(", ")
  assert_css(".eligible-bugs > .eligible_bug", count: bugs_list.size) # wait until the expected number of results have shown up

  within(".eligible-bugs") do
    bugs_list.each do |bug|
      assert_content(bug)
    end
  end
end
```